# In GIMP, how might the label on a can of soup be unwrapped?

Tags: gimp

Let's say I have a photograph of a can of soup:

[image]

How might the label on the can of soup be "unwrapped" in GIMP, resulting in a more rectilinear representation of the label?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. There's nothing automatic in GIMP or Photohsop that will do that. In GIMP manual warping with the Cage Transform or Warp Transform tool in GIMP may work. In Photoshop similarly with a Warp Transform mesh, and maybe the Liquify filter, but on an image that is so low resolution it will look horrible.

Answer (score 2):

You can try a [Displace map](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-filter-displace.html). Grey pixels in the map don't move, dark pixels move to one side, light pixels move to the other.  By using a black-to-white gradient where the grey is on the middle of the can you can stretch the extremities more than the center:

[image]

You can use Curves to give your gradient more effect on the sides:

[image]

But getting the original flat label is going to be very difficult.

The best way to shoot labels without going into full-scale slit-scan photography:

- Take multiple shots while rotating the can by a fixed amount between the shots, keep a narrow strip at the center of each shot and splice them together (manually or using a Panorama application).
- Take a smartphone with a camera that does panoramas, and rotate the can in front of it .